# How to detect TMediaPlayer state change

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I would like to know when the TMediaplayer was playing a file and finished and changed state.

in Firemonkey `TMediaplayer` has a `TMediastate` property

It only has a `GetMediastate` function, but it is not changed if a file has been playing and then finishes, `Getmediastate` Simply checks the FPlayer in (FMX.Media.iOS) has a `FPlayer.Rate > 0`

And unlike VCL there is no `OnNotify` event I can tap into.
Without using polling is there a way I can get notified that a file has finished playing?

Comment: AFAIK No. Use the application idle message to check the state - yes, that is polling